# Having trouble getting "more like this" to return any results in Haystack using Elastic Search backend

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I don't seem to be able to get the `more_like_this` tag in Haystack to return any results.  Not sure if it's down to the data I've input, but I've tried it with some documents that should very similar.

I've verified it doesn't work even with a fairly simple index like this:

```
class PaperIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Paper
```

Again the simplified model looks like:

```
class Paper(Publishable):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    abstract = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

The search template looks like:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.abstract|striptags }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

At the moment I'm just looking to see that's in the returned result from the tag like this:

```
{% more_like_this paper as related_papers limit 1 %}
{{ related_papers }}
```

Not sure if there is anything else I need to do.  The [elastic search docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html) mention "In order to use the mlt feature a mlt_field needs to be either be stored, store term_vector or source needs to be enabled."  However I'm not sure what that equates to in Haystack terms.

I should note that I'm not seeing any errors - it's just that I get back an empty list/result set from `more_like_this`.

Oh and Elastic Search is version 1.1.1.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe this feature has been broken for quite some time.  I never got it to work using solr.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was worried about.  I can probably code around it for now, but it's a shame as it would have made it such a quick feature to add.

Comment: Sadly no.  In the end I just did a manual search where I queried elastic search to find items that had been tagged with the same "subject" (with a field of "subject = indexes.MultiValueField(faceted=True)").

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still a recurring problem.

The solution is simple: provide enough information in your search template for Elastic Search to be able to calculate similarities.

If you have tags, full description, genres, languages, or anything else that could serve to find matches, add them to the search template.

To add a list (of tags for instance), you could do something like this in your search template:

```
{% load search_tags %}
{% render_tags object %}
```

And in the `search_tags` add a template tag called `render_tags`:

```
from django.template import Library
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = Library()


@register.simple_tag
def render_tags(obj):
    return mark_safe(' '.join([t.tag for t in obj.tags.all()]))
```

This assumes you have a ManyToMany relation to tags in your model.